# RangeError: Maximum call stack size error in JS function

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

```
  function findRandomDayIndex() {
    var dayindex = _.random(0, 39);
    var slot = dayslots[dayindex]; // array of 40 objects
    if(slot.filled === true || slot === undefined) {
      return findRandomDayIndex();
    } else {
      return dayindex;
    } 
  }
```

I get the error:

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded iteration of the same function

How can better write the function?

Comment: What is the `_` in `_.random(0, 39)`? Shouldn't it be `Math`?

Comment: @JonathanLam probably the Underscore or Lodash library entry point.

Comment: I think you are getting this, because no slot is free any more (or the rest is undefined). So it goes on for ever

Comment: random is the underscore.js, math gives me the same

Comment: I think some more code showing what you are doing with `dayslots` may be useful. Where do you actually set any values? I mean if all slots `filled` are `true` what stops an infinite loop, other than `RangeError`?

Comment: CodeiSir is right, moreover, you should check undefined before trying to access the "filled" property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try out this version

```
function findRandomDayIndex()
{
   var dayindex = Math.random(0, 39);
   while( ( slot = dayslots[dayindex] ) == null )
       dayindex = Math.random(0, 39);
   return dayindex ;
}
```

Please check the consistence of dayslot, in order to prevent infinite while-looping anyway

Answer (score 1):

You don't need recursion to do this. With a little refactoring you can map your array to save indexes, then filter undefined and filled values and then get random item from that new array, e.g.:

```
function findRandomDayIndex() {
    var notFilled = dayslots.map(function(value, index) {
        return {
            value: value,
            index: index
        };
    }).filter(function(day) {
        return day.value !== undefined && !day.value.filled;
    });
    if (!notFilled.length) {
        // all items of dayslots are undefined or filled
        // handle this case here
    }
    var dayindex = _.random(0, notFilled.length - 1);
    return notFilled[dayindex].index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that handles when all dayslots are filled.  The sample code returns -1, but you can update it to return anything.

```
function findRandomDayIndex() {
    // Create an array of indexes for items that aren't filled
    var m = _.map(dayslots, function(v, k) {
        if (!v.filled) {
            return k;
        }
    });
    // The array will have undefined for those already filled, so we use lodash without to remove them
    m = _.without(m, undefined);
    if (m.length === 0) {
        // Handle when all slots are filled
        return -1;
    } else {
        // return a random index
        return m[_.random(0, m.length)];
    }
}

// Lets create some test data
var dayslots = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    dayslots.push({
        filled: false
    });
}

// Test our function    
console.log(findRandomDayIndex());
```

If you change the filled to true, then you'll get a -1.

Answer (score 0):

As @CodeiSir commented since no slot was free code was going into infinite loop. So I changed the code as below and it works fine. Thank you!

```
      if (_.findWhere(dayslots, {filled: false}) !== undefined) {
          var dayindex = _.random(0, 39); 
          var slot = dayslots[dayindex];
          console.log(dayslots.length);
          if(slot.filled === true || slot === undefined) {
            return findRandomDayIndex();
          } else {
            return dayindex;
          } 
        }
```